# How to query SQL-database how many times an item has been purchased between two dates?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a beginner when it comes to databases and this question makes my brain melt. I have a database with the standard columns you would imagine: Id, price, description etc. How should I organize the database so that it's possible to query the database how many times an item has been purchased between 2012-01-08 and 2012-03-23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concur with the other answers.

```
SELECT itemcode, count(itemcode) 'times purchased', sum(quantity) 'amount purchased'  
FROM `temp_trans` 
WHERE `trans_date` >= '2012-01-08' AND `trans_date` <= '2012-03-23' 
GROUP BY itemcode
```

Here's a live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13def/1

Comment: If I were to design a purchases table I definetly go for a quantity column. So this must be the closest and more general solution, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date column called `dt` you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM your_table
WHERE dt BETWEEN 2012-01-08 AND 2012-03-23
  AND Id = your_item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, count(*)
from mytable
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-02-02'
group by id
```

This gives you the number of times each item was purchased. The field you group by will depend on how you want your result to be split up, using id or a unique name would work depending on what you want to do with the result.

The between clause is inclusive btw

Edit: good point on the comment! Probably should have said "use an appropriate field to group on, like the name or id of the item." in some of our systems description and name are used interchangeably :)

Comment: Your query works (it's syntactically correct) but I would be scared to group by description: different items could have same description! anyway, OP didn't tell us anything, so good job. +1 for you

Comment: I think you'd better using default syntax for dates: `YYYY-MM-DD`.